# Python: TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type str

Tags: python

So, I was making a text-based "shopping" program, and I came across an error that didn't quite make sense to me. The error message was this:

```
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type str
```

Here is a code snippet of where I think the error is located (Comment above line where I believe error to be located):

```
def buy():
    print "\nType in a store item to buy."
    find_item = raw_input(prompt)
    if find_item in store_items:
        print "Amount?"
        amount = raw_input(prompt)
        if amount:
                        #Error in next line?
            store_rec.append(store_items[find_item] * amount)
            get_buy()
```

If you're wondering, **store_items** is a dictionary containing the store items like this:

```
store_items = {
    "carrot": "carrot",
    "apple": "apple",
    "pear": "pear",
    "taco": "taco",
    "banana": "banana",
    "tomato": "tomato",
    "cranberry": "cranberry",
    "orange": "orange",
}
```

Then **store_rec** is an empty list, like this:

```
store_rec = []
```

It contains recommendations for telling the user what to buy next time, but that's not where I think the error is located. What I was trying to do in the line where the error appears to be, is append the amount of items specified by the user to the empty **store_rec** list. Unfortunatly, then I get the error. It seems like it should work, but it doesn't. So, with that in mind, any help on my problem is appreciated!

Comment: `raw_input` gives a string, **not** a number

Comment: Why are you trying to multiply an item by an ammount. `"carrot" * amount` does not make sence. Are you trying to add the strings?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Whoops, __int(raw_input())__

Comment: And once again, screwing up because of one __simple__ mistake. Sigh....

Comment: There's more than one mistake!

Comment: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the error carefully, it's telling you what's wrong -- it's nonsensical to multiply a sequence by a string; the string must be converted to an integer first.

Convert the amount to an integer by changing the line:

`amount = raw_input(prompt)`

to

`amount = int(raw_input(prompt))`

Comment: could float also be used? `amount = float(raw_input(prompt))`